# Open Subsets of an Simplicial Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-complex

By an simplicial complex, I mean a *finite* collection of simplexes in some Euclidean space satisfying the well known conditions. So I don't mean an abstract simplicial complex, which is purely combinatoric, but its geometric realization.

For a simplex $\sigma$, denote $\mathring\sigma$ to be its open simplex, that is, what is left of when one removes every proper faces of $\sigma$ from itself. If $K$ is a simplicial complex, it is well known that the collection of sets $\mathring\sigma$ (where $\sigma$ varies in $\sigma\in K$) partitions $|K|$, the underlying space of $K$. Moreover, if $\sigma\in K$ is a simplex having the largest dimension among $K$, we have that $\mathring\sigma$ is open in $|K|$. The analogous statement involving arbtrary simplex of $K$ is however false in general.

My question is : **Given an nonempty open subset $U$ of $|K|$, does there exist a simplex $\sigma\in K$ such that $W=U\cap\mathring\sigma$ is again an nonempty open subset of $|K|$?**

This is intuitively very clear, but I don't see how one could prove this. The textbook I'm using (Rotman, *An Introduction to Algebraic Topology*) writes that this follows from the fact that "the stars of vertices form an open cover of $|K|$". Now, I have succeeded in proving that last "fact", but I still don't understand why that fact implies the result. (The star of a vertex $p\in\text{Vert}(K)$ is, by definition, the union of all $\mathring\sigma$'s where $\sigma\in K$ has $p$ as one of its vertices, i.e. $p\in\text{Vert}(\sigma)$)

$\mathring\sigma$ is, in general, NOT open in $|K|$, so even though the star of p (denoted by $\text{st}(p)$) is an open subset of $|K|$, each $\mathring\sigma$ constituting $\text{st}(p)$ need not be an open subset... I don't see how one should proceed any further. Any suggestions?

---

P.S. I faced this problem while going through the proof of the Invariance of Dimension for simplicial complexes (Theorem 7.1 of [Rotman]). This says : *If $K$ and $L$ are simplicial complexes and if there exists a homeomorphism $f:|K|\rightarrow |L|$, then $\text{dim}(K)=\text{dim}(L)$.* Any advice in proving this fact directly would also be appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to conform more to the question as asked, and to clarify further after comments.

If $\Delta$ is a simplex of $K$ which is not contained in any higher-dimensional simplex, then the corresponding open simplex will be open in $|K|$.

Let $U$ be an open subset of $K$.  Let $\Delta$ be a closed simplex of $K$ not contained in any higher-dimensional simplex of $K$, such that $\Delta$ intersects $U$.

Let $u$ be a point in $U\cap \Delta$.  The fact that $U$ is open says that there is some radius $r$ such that all points of $\Delta$ within a distance of $r$ from $u$ are in $U$.  I claim that it is obvious that this includes points in the open simplex of $\Delta$.

One way to see this is to say that if the simplex is $d$-dimensional, we can imagine it as embedded in $\mathbb R^d$, with the faces that $u$ lies on, lying along some of the co-ordinate hyperplanes.

Then, since the intersection of U with the open simplex of $\Delta$ is non-empty and open since it is the intersection of two open sets, it satisfies the question posed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a small ball surrounding $u$ ... ' ? $U$ is an open subset of $|K|$, not an open subset of the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^{N}$. In the same spirit, what do you mean by 'the interior of $\Delta$? Interior in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$? or in $|K|$?

Comment: Sorry, I see that I didn't really address exactly your question.  Is it clear now?

Comment: I don't get it. As I mentioned in the question, open simplex need not be open in $|K|$. You must explain why the intersection of $U$ and the open simplex of $\Delta$ is open in $|K|$. Moreover, where is the maximality (of the dimension of $\Delta$) used?

Comment: Oh, I clarified my answer, but now I see that it seems that you have got the point in your answer below.  Great!

Comment: Your answer now looks great. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually I figured out a way to prove this.

---

Since $|K|$ is the disjoint union of $\mathring\sigma$s where $\sigma$ varies in $K$, there are (finitely many) $\sigma$s satisfying $U\cap\mathring\sigma\ne\emptyset$. Let $\sigma$ be one having maximal dimension among them, and fix a point $p\in U\cap\mathring\sigma$. We will show that there exist some open subset of $|K|$ that contains $p$ and is still a subset of $U\cap\mathring\sigma$. This will imply that $U\cap\mathring\sigma$ is an nonempty open subset of $|K|$, since $p$ was arbitrary.

Claim : $\text{dist}(p,\mathring\tau)>0$ for all $\tau\in K$ with $\tau\ne\sigma$. ($\text{dist}$ here means the distance in the ambient Euclidean space)

Proof : If $p\notin\tau$, closedness of $\tau$ (it is compact) gives $\text{dist}(p,\tau)>0$ which implies the result immediately. We will show that $p\in\tau$ is actually impossible. For contradiction, assume that $p\in\tau$. Now, $p$ is a point in $\mathring\sigma$, so $p\in\tau$ is possible only if $\sigma$ is a face of $\tau$. Since $\tau\ne\sigma$, $\sigma$ is a proper face of $\tau$, showing that $p$ also lies in a proper face of $\tau$. Since $U$ is an open subset of $|K|$ and $p\in U$, there exist some $\epsilon >0$ such that every point of $|K|$ less than $\epsilon$ away (in the Euclidean distance) from $p$ also belongs to $U$. But it is easy to see that we can choose a point $q\in\mathring\tau$ arbitrary close to $p$, and choosing such $q$ with $\text{dist}(p,q)<\epsilon$ implies that $U\cap\mathring\tau\ne\emptyset$ while the dimension of $\tau$ is greater than that of $\sigma$. This contradicts the maximality of $\sigma$ and the proof of the claim is complete.

From the claim above, we have that $\text{dist}(p,|K|-\mathring\sigma)>0$, since $|K|-\mathring\sigma$ is a disjoint union of (finitely many!) $\mathring\tau$s where $\tau\in K, \tau\ne\sigma$. Now choose $r>0$ small enough so that

- Every point of $|K|$ less than $r$ away from $p$ also belongs to $U$;
- $r<\text{dist}(p,|K|-\mathring\sigma)$.

By our construction, any point $q$ of $|K|$ less than $r$ away from $p$ must actually belong to $\mathring\sigma$. Let $V$ be the set of all such $q$s. Than $V$ is an open subset of $|K|$, contains $p$, $V\subset U$, and $V\subset\mathring\sigma$. We have found our desired open subset of $|K|$. Q.E.D.

---