# Simplex that's not a proper face of another simplex in a complex $K$ has open interior in $K$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex. I know from Rotman that $\mathring s$ (interior) is open in $K$ if dim $s$ = dim $K$. But I also believe this holds if $s$ is not the proper face of any other simplex in $K$.

## Claim

If $s \in K$ is not the proper face of any simplex in $K$, $\mathring s$ is open in $K$.

## (Partial) Proof

Let $s \in K$ be a simplex that is not the proper face of any other simplex in $K$. If dim $s$ = dim $K$ we're done (see Rotman exercise 7.4ii). So assume this isn't the case.

Suppose for contradiction that $\mathring s$ is not open in $K$.

**Then there exists a $t \in K$ such that $s < t$, a contradiction.**

## Question

I obviously need to elaborate on the final bolded statement in the proof. But the existence of such a $t$ seems obvious to me -- $s$ must be contained in some simplex of higher dimension $t$ if it's not open, because there has to be more ambient space in $K$ that's floating around $s$.

How do I rigorously show this?

Note: the accepted answer in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1891640/968391) asserts that my claim is true without proof, so I really think this might just be "obvious". But Rotman assigned an exercise to prove a special case of the claim (7.4ii), so I think it deserves some attention.

## Definitions

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: If $s$ is not the proper face of any simplex then the complement of its interior is a subcomplex of $K$, a subcomplex which consists of all simplices of $K$ except $s$. I'm not familiar with Rotman's book, but it's a pretty standard result that subcomplexes are closed subspaces. (it's not too difficult to prove anyway)

Comment: Thanks Mark! See my proposed proof. Per my answer, a subcomplex $L$ is a finite collection of complexes in $K$, so as a union of closed sets $|L|$ is closed in $|K|$.

Comment: Do you assume all simplicial complexes are finite? That's why I mentioned that I'm not familiar with this book, as it all depends on definitions. The standard definition is that a subcomplex is a subcollection $L$ of simplices of $K$ such that if $t\in L$ then all its faces belong to $L$ as well, and so $L$ is a simplicial complex itself. So for example, if $s$ is not a proper face of any complex in $K$ then the collection $L=K\setminus s$ clearly satisfies this, and we have $|L|=|K|\setminus  \mathring s$.

Comment: As for the topology on $|K|$, usually it is defined to be coherent with the simplices of $K$, i.e $A\subseteq |K|$ is closed iff $A\cap\sigma$ is closed in $\sigma$ for any simplex $\sigma\in K$. If $K$ is a finite complex then this topology coincides with the subspace topology from the Euclidean space, but not in general. It can be proved that if $L$ is a subcomplex then $|L|$ is closed in $|K|$, even if $L$ is not finite. But again, maybe you work with a bit different definitions.

Comment: @Mark: I updated the post to include the relevant definitions. I believe Rotman has an equivalent definition for subcomplex, which is simply a complex $L$ that's contained in $K$.

Answer (score 1):

*Claim*: $s \in K$ is not a proper face of any simplex in $K$ implies $\mathring s$ is open in $K$.

*Proof*. Let $t \in K$. Then by hypothesis, $t - \mathring s = \dot s$ if $t = s$ and is empty otherwise. This means that $|K| - \mathring s$ is the union of all simplexes in $K$ except for $s$. But this is a finite union closed sets in $K$, which is also closed in $K$. So its complement $\mathring s$ is open in $K$. $\square$